# shift a localhost site from webrick localhost:3000 to apache2 passenger localhost/redmine or redmine.localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, localhost, ruby, redmine

I have installed application called REDMINE on my localhost, using ruby on rails. It is accessible webrick script through localhost:3000, on my PC. Now I want to shift to apache2 passenger, I tried everything. Every possible link of redmine, but couldnt get it running through passenger. I installed passenger and all dependences, but still when I set virtualhost and in that put RailsBaseURI or RailsEnv etc the apache rejects it. And apache doesn't say
there is some misspelling.....

What do i have to do? How to configure it so that this ruby rail app can be accessed?

Sorry but I tried setting this up for 3 days and was not able to succeed so I am becoming little bit lunatic and crazy :)

edit:

my system : Ubuntu 12.10, apache2.2.22, Ruby-1.9.1 passenger-3.0.18

edit2:
I followed method described in this [how to install redmine](http://grandslam90.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/howto-redmine-2-0-0-passenger-subversion-repositories-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

got it working on localhost:3000 using WEBrick but i got stuck up in switching over to Apache2-passenger, i have installed all the modules of apache, gems and have enabled Vhost also but when i create a file in for [redmine](http://www.redmine.org) in sites-available folder apache fails to restart and show error of misspell....

Answer (score 1):

Port 3000 is the webserver that comes with redmine and is an out of the box webserver running WEBrick. For production, you will want to use passenger. You do this by configuring a virtual host file for apache. This should help [redmine-passenger for centos](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Redmine+Apache+Passenger_InstallOnRedHat) or [redmine-passenger for ubuntu](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu). If you are still stuck, try to create a virtual host file and paste it back in your question so we can see where it might be going wrong. Make sure iptables allows port 80 and the redmine service isn't running as that is what is making port 3000 listen on your server.

Comment: i tried following one also!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558900/changing-the-base-url-for-rails-3-development

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162196/setting-up-rails-app-on-apache-with-passenger-rails-doesnt-seem-to-load

http://grandslam90.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/howto-redmine-2-0-0-passenger-subversion-repositories-in-ubuntu-12-04/

nothing works!! i am on this since last 3 days!! :)
that might be because lack of skills(i honestly accept!!)

Comment: hi i m using ubuntu 12.10, and i had followed the same link that u gave and many others there ones but it is showing error that it is not able to know which RailsBase URI i am defining my virtualhost file is as follows 
<code>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName redmine
      Redirect permanent / localhost:3000
   <Directory /var/www/redmine>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +ExecCGI
     AllowOverride All Order allow,deny
     allow from all </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</code></pre>

Comment: stab in the dark, but if you have followed the instructions to a tee, can you ensure SELINUX is set to permissive or disabled? It is hard setting this up for the first time, so keep trying as you will get a better understanding over time

Comment: @Oli-ok sir, i'll keep on trying, but mean while i need to get this worke DONE(others are waiting) so will make this "redmine" available through webrick, then later on will switch over.. ;)

will post update if successful!!